# Transmisson problems 2009 sierra 1500

Tags: automatic-transmission, gmc, sierra

I have a '09 GMC Sierra 5.3 rwd it has just under 80k miles. I was driving home and my truck felt like transmission wasnt accelerating pulled over and shut it off. Looking around trans fluid was all underneath the rear of my truck and some on my tailgate. So i dumped a gal of trans but it won't move. Shifting from park to neutral and giving it some gas still feels like it's in drive. But won't move. Took driveline off but idk what I'm looking for.

[image]

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a 2wd or 4wd model?

Comment: Its 2wd. Blah blah haha. Gotta get the min charater count. Ha

Comment: Is there any way you could get pictures of the sides of the yoke (end of the driveshaft) and a more side on of the end of the transmission? It looks as though, the rear seal may have gone out. This wouldn't make the transmission stop working, but is an issue. This is more than likely something you're going to have to take to a tranny shop to get fixed.

Comment: Ya... Im the one that "fixed" the seal. I just bought the whole housing. New bushing and whatever else. Yah i can get more pics.

Comment: I just posted some more pics. Hard to get good angles.

Comment: Does the truck roll just fine without the driveshaft in place?

Comment: Haha id say so I just started removing it (without a second thought) and needless to say yah it rolls just fine.

Comment: As much as I'd like to help, I think your truck is destined for the tranny shop. There's nothing I can see which is jumping out at me from the pictures or what you described.

Comment: Where's the tail shaft seal in the pics? Did it fall off?